# Sorting by calculated column in SQL Server not working

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following query and want to order the list by User name

```
select distinct
    SUBSTRING(u.FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', u.FullName) + 1, LEN(u.FullName)) + ',     ' + SUBSTRING(u.FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', u.FullName) - 1) as UserName
from 
    Users u
where 
    u.Active = 1
order by 
    SUBSTRING(u.FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', u.FullName) + 1, LEN(u.FullName)) + ', ' + SUBSTRING(u.FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', u.FullName) - 1)
```

The problem here is two of the users with last name r and w always show at top of the list, while the rest of the list is sorted A to Z.

Any suggestion how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, the two user that show at top of the list, their full name was stored in data base with two spaces between first and last name.
left `trim` fixes the issue.